# Changing style of an image next to a checked radio button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the background colour of an image which is next to each radio button in a group, when the relevant button is checked. I used the following HTML and CSS:

```css
.option-choice:checked img.img-thumbnail {
    background-color: #004990 !important;
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input class="option-choice" name="option[227]" value="18" type="radio">
         <img src="imageurl.jpg" alt="20mm " class="img-thumbnail">20mm
    </label>
</div>
```

Yet the CSS does not work, and the image remains unchanged. Is it possible my CSS is not correct here, or is it just not possible to do this?

Comment: A space between selectors in CSS will look for *descendants*. For example, `.first .second` will look for `.second` elements that are *descendants* of `.first` elements. For general siblings, you'd use `~`. Though in your case, being that the two are *adjacent siblings*, you can use `+`: `.option-choice:checked + img.img-thumbnail`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This..

```
.option-choice:checked img.img-thumbnail {
  background-color: #004990 !important;
  border-color: red;
}
```

assumes that the image is a **descendant** of the `input` which it is not.

Use the *Adjacent Sibling* Selector `+`

```
.option-choice:checked + img.img-thumbnail {
  background-color: #004990 !important;
  border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think its more appropriate to say it assumes that the image is a descendant.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector has to be `.option-choice:checked + img.img-thumbnail`:

```css
.option-choice:checked + img.img-thumbnail {
  background-color: #004990 !important;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input class="option-choice" name="option[227]" value="18" type="radio">
     <img src="imageurl.jpg" alt="20mm " class="img-thumbnail">20mm
     </label>
</div>
```